# org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction not found from bundle in Karaf based container

Tags: java, osgi, apache-commons, validation, apache-karaf

i am getting following exception at the time of deploying a bundle on karaf based container,
PS. i am not getting this in Eclipse at the time of running JUnit tests.

```
2013-09-05 20:07:59,935[qtp32887324-149]|ERROR|<mypackage>.registration.validateuserdata.service.impl.ValidateUserDataSvcImpl|SAXExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber
: 37; Error at line 9 char 37: org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction not found from bundle [dsp.core]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 37; Error at line 9 char 37: org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction not found from bundle [dsp.core]
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3181)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3207)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1456)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
        at org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorResources.<init>(ValidatorResources.java:163)
        at org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorResources.<init>(ValidatorResources.java:137)
        at <mypackage>.registration.validateuserdata.service.impl.ValidateUserDataSvcImpl.validateProfile(ValidateUserDataSvcImpl.java:213)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:355)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:319)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1040)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:976)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:931)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:992)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction not found from bundle [dsp.core]
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:103)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:156)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:175)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1453)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction not found by dsp.core [195]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:670)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1654)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:909)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:99)
```

NOTE: dsp.core is a wrapper on Apache Karaf

can anyone please help me resolving the same?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bundle `dsp.core` should import the package `org.apache.commons.validator`.

Comment: Dsp.core is already a stable wrapper over karaf. This issue is coming only when I try deploying my bundle.

Comment: I don't know what "stable wrapper over karaf" means. I'm interpreting the error message for you.

Comment: By wrapper I mean its an API layer over karaf which gives simple implementation for basic requirements like logging, exception handling etc.

Comment: That it is stable outside of OSGi does not mean it already contains a correct Manifest.